# How to get Lightrun running in IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, remote-debugging, intellij-plugin

No matter what I do Lightrun will generate the following error message:

General agent error at jvm_internals.cc:186.

This is my first time using Lightrun.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Scanner(System.in).nextInt() + new Scanner(System.in).nextInt());
    }
}
```

The code itself runs perfectly.

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1.

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Comment: @DrorBereznitsky I am using java 19.

Comment: Lightrun 1.10 release includes java 19 support which should resolve this issue - see release notes https://docs.lightrun.com/release_notes/v1.10/

Answer (score 0):

LR doesn’t work on this version. A bit buggy on the ij versions for the past 2 months…

Comment: On which IntelliJ versions does it work?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).